# Can't get rid of Gnome SSH Agent

Tags: 14.04, gnome-keyring, ssh-agent

When I type in a terminal `git -T git@github.com` the dialog with the title "Unlock private key" appears with password entry field.

I guess it is Gnome Keyring SSH Agent, and I would like not to use it but to use instead `ssh-add` command to add keys.

I edited `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop` but that didn't help. In "Startup Applications" settings it looks as disabled.

```
  1 [Desktoktop Entry] 
  2 Type=Application 
  3 Name=SSH Key Agent 
  4 Comment=GNOME Keyring: SSH Agent 
  5 Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh 
  6 OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity; 
  7 X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Initialization 
  8 X-GNOME-AutoRestart=false 
  9 X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=false 
 10 X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME 
 11 X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-keyring 
 12 X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general 
 13 X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.2.2 
 14 NoDisplay=false 
 15 X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-keyring
```

Finaly how can I disable Gnome SSH Agent?

Comment: Try `unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK` before calling `ssh`, or `env SSH_AUTH_SOCK= git ...` (comment and not an answer because I can't check it from here).

Comment: That breaks ssh-add either

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to run the autostart file for ssh-agent, just add:

```
Hidden = true
```

to it's .desktop file in either `/etc/xdg/autostart` or in `~/.config/autostart`

If you aren't the only user of the system, you might want to copy the .desktop file to `~/.config/autostart` and set the `Hidden` entry in there. It should override the system wide setting for your user account, [if the standard is respected](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html).

The [Gnome documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Ssh) also explains how to use ssh-add with the gnome-keyring, just note that the section about `gnome-session-properties` is outdated, as that utility is deprecated and removed from recent versions.

I would also consult the [man page for ssh-add](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add) to understand what exactly it does.

Btw, I did a [little research](https://gist.github.com/najamelan/b44e943145b03e018229) into the gnome extensions to the desktop entry standard.

Comment: This is *the* solution, it even works by setting it in ~/.config/autostart.